# _beginthreadx and socket

Tags: c++

i have a question about the _beginthreadx function In the third and fourth parameter:

if i have this line to create the thread

```
hThread=(HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0,0, &RunThread, &m_socket,CREATE_SUSPENDED,&threadID );
```

`m_socket` is the socket that i want inside the thread (fourth parameter)

and i have the RunThread function (third parameter) in this way

```
static unsigned __stdcall RunThread (void* ptr) {
    return 0;
}
```

It is sufficient to create the thread independently if m_socket has something or not?

### Thanks in advance

Thank you for the response Ciaran Keating helped me understand better the thread

I'll explain a little more the situation

I´m creating the tread in this function inside a class

public: void getClientsConnection()
    {
        numberOfClients = 1;
        SOCKET temporalSocket = NULL;
        firstClient = NULL;
        secondClient = NULL;

```
    while (numberOfClients < 2)
    {
        temporalSocket = SOCKET_ERROR;
        while (temporalSocket == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            temporalSocket = accept(m_socket, NULL, NULL);
            //-----------------------------------------------
            HANDLE hThread;
             unsigned threadID;

            hThread=(HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0,0, &RunThread, &m_socket,CREATE_SUSPENDED,&threadID );
            WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
                                if(!hThread)
                                     printf("ERROR AL CREAR EL HILO: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                                //-----------------------------------------------

        }
        if(firstClient == NULL)
        {
            firstClient = temporalSocket;
            muebleC1 = temporalSocket;
            actionC1 = temporalSocket;
            ++numberOfClients;
            printf("CLIENTE 1 CONECTADO\n");
        }
        else
        {
            secondClient = temporalSocket;
            muebleC2 = temporalSocket;
            actionC2 = temporalSocket;
            ++numberOfClients;
            printf("CLIENTE 2 CONECTADO\n");
        }
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to do is to have the socket inside the thread while wait for a client connection

Is this feasible as i have the code of the thread?

I can change the state of the thread that is not a problem

Thanks again

Comment: "if m_socket has something or not"? Can you please rephrase the question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will create the thread and pass it your socket handle. But by returning immediately from RunThread your new thread will terminate immediately after you resume it (you've created it suspended.) You'll need to put your socket handling code (read/write loop etc.) inside RunThread.

Some more tips:

You'll have to make sure that m_socket remains valid for the life of the thread, because you passed it by reference. You might prefer to pass it by value instead, and let ownership pass to the new thread, but of course in that case it probably wouldn't belong in your object instance (I infer from the m_ prefix.) Or you might prefer to leave the socket handle in the object instance, and pass a reference to the object to beginthread instead:

```
beginthread(...,&RunThread,this,...);
```

Comment: Or maybe you meant to pass the address of m_socket and then assign to it later, and perhaps resume the thread at that time? That would work too. Just be sure that the pointer remains valid.

Comment: Tanks for the help, sorry i can´t vote up to you because i have not 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

(With your new info, I can see that my other answer isn't what you need.)

If I understand you right, you just want to wait on the accept() call until a client connects. You don't need threads for that - there are native sockets ways to do it. One option is to make m_socket a blocking socket, so accept() doesn't return until a client connects. An easier way is to use the select() function to wait until the socket is ready to read, which in the case of a listening socket means that a client has connected.

```
fd_set fds;
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(m_socket,&fds);
int ret = select(0,&fds,NULL,NULL,NULL); // will block
if(FD_ISSET(m_socket,&fds))
    temporalSocket = accept(...);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! You helped me greatly. A question more, How can I verify that are passing messages through the socket after implementing the code that you suggests to me? I am sorry if the answer is obvious but this kind of code is new for me

Comment: After the accept() call completes you have a connected socket (temporalSocket) and you're ready to start reading/writing your messages over that socket.